# MS remote desktop virtualization: new-RDVirtualDesktopCollection error creating vdi pool

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-desktop-services, windows-server-2012-r2, hyper-v-server-2012-r2

I'm experimenting with my first setup of MS virtual desktop virtualization and have hit a problem I can't get over. I switched over from using the gui to powershell to try and identify the issue. It occurs when I try and create the Desktop collection from the template.

What I have is:

- 1 hyper-v on win 2012 R2 (HyperVServer)
- 1 win 2012 Std server  (RDServer) which will have/has each of the other roles involved.
- DCs are our normal DC's in the office here.
- 1 vm with win7sp1pro, patched and updated the integration tools and then sysprepped
- The servers are in spanish

NOTE: I have noticed mention of installing win7 enterprise, which I hope is not a requirement for this to work as I only have pro licenses to experiment with. I can't find this mentioned as being a requirement...

From the RDServer I execute the following:

```
new-RDVirtualDesktopCollection -CollectionName myVDIPool -PooledManaged 
-Virtual DesktopTemplateName VDIBaseWin7 
-VirtualDesktopTemplateHostServer hypervserver.mydom.com 
-VirtualDesktopAllocation @{"hypervserver.mydom.com"=1} 
-StorageType localstorage 
-ConnectionBroker RDServer.mydom.com 
-VirtualDesktopNamePrefix msVDI
```

which responds (in spanish - I'll translate below) with

```
Confirmar
No se concedió acceso a la unidad organizativa CN=Computers,DC=mydom,DC=com. ¿Desea pasarlo por alto y continuar?
[S] Sí  [N] No  [U] Suspender  [?] Ayuda (el valor predeterminado es "S"): s
No se pudieron obtener detalles del escritorio virtual para VDIBaseWin7 del servidor HyperVSrv.mydom.com.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidResult: (:) [], WorkflowTerminatedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : JobStateFailed
    + PSComputerName        : localhost

new-RDVirtualDesktopCollection : No se pudo crear la colección de escritorios virtuales. Error:
En línea: 1 Carácter: 1
+ new-RDVirtualDesktopCollection -CollectionName VDIPool -PooledManaged  -Virtu ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,New-RDVirtualDesktopCollection
```

It asks to grant access to the computers.mydom.com ou - ok, no problem. But it then fails with "No se pudieron obtener detalles del escritorio virtual para VDIBaseWin7 del servidor HyperVSrv.mydom.com" which translates as:

```
Unable to obtain details for the virtual desktop for VDIBaseWin7 on server hypervsrv
```

or

```
Cannot obtain details for the virtual desktop for VDIBaseWin7 on server hypervsrv
```

obviously the command is trying to do something remotely with hyperv, but I cannot work out what.

Does anyone have any idea what this command may be attempting to do when it fails? If I had an idea of what it was trying to do I could work out what was wrong, but this doesn't give much info.... 'cannot obtain details' isn't the most helpful of errors.

**edit**: I've tried trawling through the powershell code in C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\RemoteDesktop and other places looking for the source to the function to try and work out what its doing, but no luck, can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my own problem. After wasting much time I decided to try out the same process but using windows 2012R2 for the rds server. The wizard found everything and created the collection without complaint. I'm sure theres probably a doc somewhere which says use 2012R2...